# Preloading page between two asp.net pages

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I posed a question that related where I could display "Page loading"  in asp.net page using jQuery. But, I had no luck.

So, say I have page1 and it navigates to page2 and page2 doesn't some heavy data access. Is there any way I could show the "preloading" page while the page2 is finished.

I want to navigate from Page1 -> "Preload" -> Page2(once page2 is completed).

I want to know if this is possible using Javascript in the code behind.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you create a database view that makes the data access more to the point? We've transformed several heavy pages into snappy quick loading ones by making the database join and filter the data for us.

Comment: Maybe this is a use for asynchronous pages? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx  Haven't tried them myself though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using JavaScript is OK, redirect the user to the Preload page, and then use JavaScript to take the user to Page2. This will make the Preload page stay visible while Page2 is loading.

(Also, "JavaScript in the codebehind"? Don't tell me you're using JScript.NET or something as your server side language)

Comment: No, I just meant javascript.  Could you direct me how I can use the Javascript to take user to Page2 from the "preload" page?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Matti, I used your example and it work now. Now, my another question is there any way I could detect the previous page in the javascript so that I can redirect to right page. I want to use the "Preload page" as common page for other pages where I want to show the loading page. But,they all be redirected to different pages so I want check the previous page and redirect to Appropriate pages. Thanks everybody for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The way you would typically do this is have a page that shows the message and uses AJAX, in my example using jQuery, to load the other page onto the current page.

```
<body>
   <div id="content">
   Page loading
   </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#content').load('/url/to/other/page');
        });
   </script>
</body>
```

I've omitted loading jQuery itself.

**Note:** you could do this on a single page by having it generate different content based on some query parameter.  You don't need to actually have a separate "loading" page -- though you could probably make that work for several different pages as well.

Comment: +1 I'd agree that using jquery/javascript to load in the content after page load would solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you do, to begin loading Page2 you'll have to navigate away from Page1 (unless you get complicated and wrap your pages in another container on a single page and navigate within your container).

Otherwise the default content for Page2 should be a "Preloading" message that gets taken away once the document has finished loading its content.

Answer (score 0):

Is a possible solution to have an almost empty page with a few placeholder divs in the right places containing a loading image.  Then run web service calls to populate each placeholder in jquery/javascript?